# Dynamically adding methods with or without metaclass

Tags: python, metaclass

**Update - 2012/12/13**

Just to clarify - I'm not so much interested in ways how to add methods to classes - as you can see below in my question and in people's answers, there is more than one way to do that (tongue in cheek and hat tip to my Perl self).

The thing I am interested in is learning what's the fundamental difference of adding methods to classes using different approaches and the big question really is why do I need to use metaclasses for. For example [A Primer on Python Metaclass Programming](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html) states that:

> Perhaps the most common use of metaclasses [...]: adding, deleting, renaming, or substituting methods for those defined in the produced class.

And since there's more ways to do that, I'm puzzled and looking for explanation.

Thanks!

**Original - 2012/12/12**

I need to dynamically add methods to a class (and newly generated classes based on that class). I came up with two approaches, one involving metaclass, the other one doing without one. I cannot see any difference in what the two approaches give me other than the fact the latter doesn't involve the "black magic" metaclass ;)

Approach *#1* **with** metaclass:

```
class Meta(type):
        def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                setattr(cls, "foo", lambda self: "foo@%s(class %s)" % (self,
                        cls.__name__))

class Y(object):
        __metaclass__ = Meta

y = Y()
y.foo() # Gives 'foo@<__main__.Y object at 0x10e4afd10>(class Y)'
```

Approach *#2* **without** metaclass:

```
class Z(object):
        def __init__(self):
                setattr(self.__class__, "foo",
                        lambda self: "foo@%s(class %s)" %
                        (self, self.__class__.__name__))

z = Z()
z.foo() # Gives 'foo@<__main__.Z object at 0x10c865dd0>(class Z)'
```

As far as I can tell, both approaches give me the same results and "expressivity". Even when I try to create a new classes using `type("NewClassY", (Y, ), {})` or `type("NewClassZ", (Z, ), {})` I get the same expected results which don't differ between the two approaches.

So, I'm wondering if there really is any "underlying" difference in the approaches, or if there's anything which will "bite" me later if I used either *#1* or *#2* or if it's just a syntactic sugar?

PS: *Yes, I did read the other threads here talking about metaclasses in Python and pythonic data model.*

Comment: Can you call `Y.foo` and `Z.foo` using both approaches?

Comment: The difference is that the metaclass will create the methods at the time the class is defined and the `__init__`way will create the methods when you instantiate the class. There is also multiple inheritance (mixins) which you can use to add methods.

Comment: @Blender No, you cannot call them like that since they are not "class methods".

Comment: @JochenRitzel Interesting and in accordance with my observation. But is there anything which one approach won't let me do and the other one will?

Answer (score 9):

The obvious reason to use metaclasses is because they really provide metadata about the class as soon as the class is known, unrelated to the presence of objects or not. Trivial, right? Well, let us show some commands I executed on your original `Z` and `Y` classes to see what this means:

```
In [287]: hasattr(Y,'foo')
Out[287]: True

In [288]: hasattr(Z,'foo')
Out[288]: False

In [289]: Y.__dict__
Out[289]:
<dictproxy {..., 'foo': <function __main__.<lambda>>}>

In [290]: Z.__dict__
Out[290]:
<dictproxy {...}>

In [291]: z= Z()

In [292]: hasattr(Z,'foo')
Out[292]: True

In [293]: Z.__dict__
Out[293]:
<dictproxy {..., 'foo': <function __main__.<lambda>>}>

In [294]: y = Y()

In [295]: hasattr(Y,'foo')
Out[295]: True

In [296]: Y.__dict__
Out[296]:
<dictproxy {..., 'foo': <function __main__.<lambda>>}>
```

As you can see the second version actually alters the class Z significantly after it's been declared, something you often like to avoid. It is certainly not an uncommon operation for python to do operations on 'types' (class objects) and you likely want them to be as consistent as possible, certainly for this case (where the method is not really dynamic at runtime, just at declaration time).

One application that jumps to mind is documenation. If you'd add a docstring to `foo` using the metaclass, documentation might pick it up, via the `__init__` method this is very unlikely.

It could also lead to hard-to-spot bugs. consider a piece of code that uses metainformation of a class. It could be that in 99.99% of the cases this is executed after an instance of `Z` is already created, but that 0.01% can lead to weird behaviour, if not crashes.

It could also get tricky in hierarchy chains, where you'd have to take good care where to call the parent's constructor. A class like this for example could give issues:

```
class Zd(Z):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()
        Z.__init__(self)
a = Zd()
...
AttributeError: 'Zd' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

While this works fine:

```
class Yd(Y):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()
        Y.__init__(self)
a = Yd()
```

It might seem stupid to call a method without the relevant `__init__` being used but it can happen when you're not careful, and certainly in more complex hierarchies where the MRO is not immediately obvious. And it's hard to spot this error because most often Zd() will succeed as soon as `Z.__init__` was called somewhere before.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is adding methods dynamically, python does handle it in a quite straightforward manner. It goes as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Alpha():

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 100

alpha = Alpha()
print alpha.a
print alpha.b

def foo(self):
    print self.a * self.b * self.c

Alpha.c = 1000
Alpha.d = foo

beta = Alpha()
beta.d()
```

Output:

```
$ python script.py 
10
100
1000000
```

Regards!

P.S.: I see no resemblance of black magic here (:

**Edit:**

Considering martineau's comment, I'm adding `data attributes`, not `method function attributes`. I really can see no difference between doing `Alpha.d = foo` and `Alpha.d = lambda self: foo(self)`, except that I'd be using a lambda function as a wrapper to the function `foo` added.

The addition of the method is the same, and python itself name both additions the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Alpha():

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 100

alpha = Alpha()
print alpha.a
print alpha.b

def foo(self):
    print self.a * self.b * self.c

Alpha.c = 1000

Alpha.d = lambda self: foo(self)
Alpha.e = foo

print Alpha.d
print Alpha.e

a = Alpha()
a.d()
a.e()
```

Output:

```
10
100
<unbound method Alpha.<lambda>>
<unbound method Alpha.foo>
1000000
1000000
```

As shown, python itself name both resultant additions as methods -- the only difference is that one is a reference to function `foo`, and the other is a reference to a lambda function  that uses the function `foo` in its definition body.

If I said something wrong, please, correct me.

Regards!

Comment: Your answer does not add methods to the class, it only adding data attributes, not method function attributes.

Comment: would you mind to give an example of what is a `method function attribute`?

Comment: `Alpha.answer = lambda self: 42`

Comment: I've added an edit, according to your answer; would you mind to take a look at it, please?

Comment: Thanks guys, but I wasn't looking for way how to add methods to classes. The thing I was interested in (maybe my question phrasing wasn't goo enough, sorry for that) was whether one approach (metaclass one) was fundamentally different from the other approach (adding the method in __init__ of the class itself and doing `setattr(self.__class__. ...)`. @JochenRitzler above explained one difference.

Comment: TomasHeran: No, the phrasing of your question and particularly its title weren't "goo" enough—in fact they're very misleading if that's what you really want to know.