# Dynamically adding methods with metaclass "__init__" vs "__new__"

Tags: python, dynamic, metaclass

Continuing the discussion from this question: [Dynamically adding methods with or without metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850114/dynamically-adding-methods-with-or-without-metaclass-in-python), when doing the dynamic injetion, what is the difference and benefits/issues of doing it in the `__new__` method vs. the `__init__` method?

In the referenced question the new method is added by using `setattr`. If you do this in the`__new__` method, you need to modify the `dict` parameter. Using the same example, it would be something like this:

```
class Meta(type)
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        def my_method(self, x):
            return x in self.letters

        dct[my_method.__name__] = my_method
        return super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If you do this in the new method, you need to modify the dict parameter

Well, not necessarily, you can as well use `setattr` *after* you created the new class object, ie:

```
class Meta(type)
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        def my_method(self, x):
            return x in self.letters

        newclass =  super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)
        setattr(newclass, my_method.__name__, my_method)
        return newclass
```

So basically, in `Meta.__init__` you can only modify the already instanciated class object, while in `Meta.__new__` you can inspect and modify the parents and namespace *before* creating the class *and* modify the created class afterward.

So what's the point of using `__init__` at all ? Well sometimes you don't need all the power `__new__` gives you only want to modify the newly created class, and then `__init__` saves you the extra boilerplate of creating the class.